# Change SQL SERVER query to POSTGRES

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Hi i just found query for night shift attendance and trying to convert from SQL Server query to Postgres query like below and its say ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 12: WHERE ein.c2 = '0'

Postgres query:

```
    SELECT ein.userid,ein.logdate AS LogIn,ca_out.logdate AS LogOut
    FROM employee AS ein
    LEFT JOIN 
    (select eout.logdate 
     from employee AS eout 
     WHERE eout.userid = ein.userid 
     AND eout.c2='1' 
     AND eout.logdate >=  ein.logdate
     ORDER BY eout.logdate 
     LIMIT 1) ca_out 
     JOIN shift AS s ON s.userid = ein.userid
     WHERE ein.c2 = '0'
     ORDER BY UserID,LogIn;
```

This is the original query.
SQL Server Query:

```
SELECT
    EIn.UserID
    ,CAST(DATEADD(minute, -ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight, EIn.LogDate) AS date) AS dt
    ,EIn.LogDate AS LogIn
    ,CA_Out.LogDate AS LogOut
    ,DATEDIFF(minute, EIn.LogDate, CA_Out.LogDate) AS WorkingMinutes
FROM
    @Employee AS EIn
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) EOut.LogDate
        FROM @Employee AS EOut
        WHERE
            EOut.UserID = EIn.UserID
            AND EOut.C1 = 'Out'
            AND EOut.LogDate >= EIn.LogDate
        ORDER BY EOut.LogDate
    ) AS CA_Out
    INNER JOIN @Shifts AS S ON S.UserID = EIn.UserID
WHERE
    EIn.C1 = 'In'
ORDER BY
    UserID
    ,LogIn
;
```

So can you help to to convert this into postgresql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate error is that you are missing the JOIN condition after `as ca_out`.

But the equivalent of SQL Server's (non-standard) `CROSS APPLY` is a `cross join lateral` which doesn't require a join condition.

I am not familiar with the dateadd and datediff functions, but you probably want something like:

```
SELECT ein.userid, 
       (ein.logdate - make_interval(mins => ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight))::date AS dt, 
       ein.logdate,
       ca_out.logdate AS logout,
       extract(epoch from ca_out.logdate - ein.logdate) / 60 as working_minutes
FROM employee AS ein
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    select eout.logdate 
    from employee AS eout 
    WHERE eout.userid = ein.userid 
    AND eout.c2 = '1' 
    AND eout.logdate >=  ein.logdate
    ORDER BY eout.logdate 
    LIMIT 1
  ) ca_out 
  JOIN shift AS s ON s.userid = ein.userid
WHERE ein.c2 = '0'
ORDER BY UserID,LogIn;
```

I don't know how the cross apply works in SQL Server, but if you expect the query in the derived table `ca_out` to not return any rows, but you still need the row from outer query, you will need to change it to an outer join and provide a dummy join condition:

```
select ...
from employee ein
   left join lateral ( 
      ...
   ) as ca_out on true
   JOIN shift AS s ON s.userid = ein.userid
where ...
```

---

Note that if `employee.c2` is a number (`integer` or `numeric`) you should compare it with a number not with a character value, e.g. `ein.c2 = 0`

Answer (score 0):

There is missing one `ON` clause for `LEFT JOIN`. Maybe you want to use `CROSS JOIN` instead `LEFT JOIN`.